# Convert a CSV file with array columns to JSON file for MongoDB

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, csv

i'm trying to import a csv file containing columns as arrays into a a Json file for MongoDB but when import the file with MongoDB it recognize the column containing the array as a String.
This is what i have:

```
 _id: ObjectId("61f40cbf61f97f53a9aa4946"),
  name: 'Zipang',
  episodes: 26,
  premiered: 2004,
  genre: '[\'Action\', \'Military\', \'Sci-Fi\', \'Historical\', \'Drama\', \'Seinen\']' }
```

But i want it to be like this:

```
 _id: ObjectId("61f40cbf61f97f53a9aa4946"),
  name: 'Zipang',
  episodes: 26,
  premiered: 2004,
  genre: ["Action", "Military", "Sci-Fi", "Historical", "Drama", "Seinen"] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.updateMany({ genre: { $not: { $type: "array" } } }, [
   {
      $set: {
         genre: {
            $split: [{ $trim: { input: "$genre", chars: "[]" } }, ","]
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         genre: {
            $map: { input: "$genre", in: { $trim: { input: "$$this", chars: " '" } } }
         }
      }
   },
])
```

Comment: It seems to work after  but it doesn't edit the jsons, it only shows the documents genre field as an array after the query
I need to change the field to an array in order to work with it's fields in java

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: I managed to update it with your last command but with the new one it returns the error:
"input to $map must be an array not string"

Comment: Your old code worked fine! i paste it if anyone will need it in the future! 
Thanks a lot you saved my day!!!
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         genre: {
            $split: [{ $trim: { input: "$genre", chars: "[]" } }, ","]
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         genre: {
            $map: { input: "$genre", in: { $trim: { input: "$$this", chars: " '" } } }
         }
      }
   },
 
])